# Options to Repair Wooden Floors?

Tags: repair, wood, floor, hardwood-floor

I rent an apartment and work from home. Unfortunately, I didn’t consider the damage the chair would cause to the floor until it was too late. Are there any options for repairing this myself? I’m fairly handy but unsure where to start.

[image: Floor Damage]

Comment: Or this? [How to fix drag marks on wooden floor?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/107660/35141)

Comment: Or this? [How to fix hardwood floor with wear from an office chair](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/70329/35141)